# Different HMAC result for JAVA and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, hmac, sha

I'm trying to generate HMAC based on string value and key

```
public static byte[] hmacSha1(String value, String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    // some values hardcoded for simplicity of this code sample
    key = "GET\\n?nodeList\\nThu, 10 Jul 2014 13:35:32 GMT\\nda39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709\\n";;
    value = "6020834c535670ab1da86f7697241cb43ab6fb90";
    final String type = "HmacSHA1";
    final String charset = "ASCII";

    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        keyBytes = key.getBytes(charset);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, type);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(type);
    mac.init(secret);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        bytes = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes(charset));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "bytes to hex: " + bytesToHex(bytes));
    // result Android:  512B5CE2EA1CD71FF34C9DDB693F59288EF71B42
    // iOS: 96f852a08d3ee255b77364a6bbd106be0dc0e44e

    return bytes;
}
```

And Android result (hex value) doesn't match the one that has iOS app (using same string value and key).

```
(NSString *)HMAC_SHA1WithKeyData:(NSData* )key
{
const char * cData = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, [key bytes], [key length], cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                      length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

const unsigned char * buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMAC bytes];
NSMutableString *HMACString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMAC.length* 2];
for (int i = 0; i < HMAC.length; i++) {
    [HMACString appendFormat:@“%02x”, buffer[i]];
}

return HMACString;
}
```

Android HMAC (hex): 512B5CE2EA1CD71FF34C9DDB693F59288EF71B42

iOS HMAC:  96f852a08d3ee255b77364a6bbd106be0dc0e44e

Can someone clarify please how can i get the same HMAC as iOS does (cause it matches the back-end result).

Comment: sory for some code formatting issues, couldn't find the correct way to paste iOS part

Answer (score 1):

Finally i reached the result same as with iOS only using openssl C library (pre-built for NDK), here is cpp code:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_speicherbox_speicherbox_utils_CryptoUtils_hmac(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jstring key_, jstring data_) {

    char *keyString = const_cast<char *>(env->GetStringUTFChars(key_, 0));
    unsigned  char *key = datahex(keyString);
    const char *data = env->GetStringUTFChars(data_, 0);

    //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "______________________ key: %s", key);
    //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "______________________ data: %s", data);

    unsigned int result_len;
    unsigned char result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

    HMAC(
            EVP_sha1(),
            key,
            SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH,
            (unsigned char*)data,
            strlen(data),
            result,
            &result_len
    );

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(key_, keyString);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(data_, data);

    jbyteArray hmacBytes = env->NewByteArray(result_len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(hmacBytes, 0, result_len,  (jbyte*)result);

    return hmacBytes;
}
```